# How can I abstract static instance/collection generators?

Tags: java

What I'm talking about are those static functions that generate objects, such as:

```
class MyClass {
  public static MyClass fromOtherClass(OtherClass foo) { ... }
}
```

In my specific case, I have interface `Window` that represents program window. It has methods like `click`, `minimize` and so on. Obviously, there are many options to get window instances. I'd love to have following abstract static methods:

```
public abstract static Window byTitle(String windowTitle);
public abstract static List<Window> filterAll(WindowValidator validator); //WindowValidator is simple callback interface
public abstract static Window byThreadID(int id);
```

These three methods are all valid on any GUI OS I know therefore I see no reason for them not to be abstract - except that Java denies it.

Whenever somebody hits the tight boundaries of Java, other developer remind him that his design is somewhat flawed. I am aware that in Java, static methods are bound to class definitions.

My question is how should I properly implement this, since static abstract methods are nonsense.

Comment: Sounds like a case for SPI.

Comment: It sounds like you should have an abstract `WindowManager` class or something like that...

Comment: do you mean a factory class or something like that?

Comment: @JonSkeet And where (and why) would I instantiate `WindowManager`? Mind that the OS supplies window information and there's nothing an instance could hold inside itself.

Comment: @TomášZato: There'd probably be a static `WindowManager.getInstance` method or something like that. It's a fairly common pattern - see `Runtime.getRuntime` for example. Or it could be via an SPI for different GUIs, like XML document factories.

Comment: @JonSkeet If it's static, it can't be abstract - and we're just where we started. I don't know what SPI is, I'll google it.

Comment: @TomášZato: The *class* can be abstract, but a method within it being static. I didn't say it would be an abstract static class. (Admittedly java.lang.Runtime *isn't* abstract, but it easily could be. Look at Charset as another example - it's abstract but with various static factory methods.)